# React Native Javascript exceptions

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native

I've got an Android react native app on the store and in the stats of the app recently I can see some JavaScript exceptions and I'm provided with some error code. I've read looking for something to tell me where is the error in my code or when this error pops to the end user but haven't been able to find a solution. Any idea how can I solve this or what this text means?

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is not an object (evaluating 'n._currentElement'), stack:
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6700
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
performUpdateIfNecessary@139:5029
performUpdateIfNecessary@130:963
s@126:940
perform@134:617
perform@134:617
perform@126:2082
k@126:2254
closeAll@134:1270
perform@134:704
batchedUpdates@210:485
o@126:412
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@117:647
receiveEvent@117:757
value@30:2778
<unknown>@30:1013
<unknown>@30:106
value@30:985
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke (BaseJavaModule.java:345)
  at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:136)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

The second error I get is this one:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.getHostNode'), stack:
getHostNode@130:343
getHostNode@139:3247
getHostNode@130:355
updateChildren@137:515
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
updateChildren@137:471
_reconcilerUpdateChildren@135:955
_updateChildren@135:1807
updateChildren@135:1695
receiveComponent@115:817
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
receiveComponent@139:4813
receiveComponent@130:601
_updateRenderedComponent@139:6780
_performComponentUpdate@139:6549
updateComponent@139:5788
performUpdateIfNecessary@139:5029
performUpdateIfNecessary@130:963
s@126:940
perform@134:617
perform@134:617
perform@126:2082
k@126:2254
closeAll@134:1270
perform@134:704
batchedUpdates@210:485
o@126:412
_receiveRootNodeIDEvent@117:647
receiveTouches@117:1021
value@30:2778
<unknown>@30:1013
<unknown>@30:106
value@30:985
at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java
  at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException (ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke (BaseJavaModule.java:345)
  at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:136)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: The store is not telling me where the error is, the only thing i got is what i already put. The code of the app is so long to put all of it here.

Comment: I experienced the second one as well. No idea what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Without code I can hardly answer, but here is my guess:

The errors are saying that a variable is not filled or does not (yet) exist, while your code is asking for it somewhere.
Try to find 'n._currentElement' and 'e.getHostNode', I suggest using Cmd/Ctrl + F. If you can find where these variables are used, maybe you can also figure out where the error is being generated.

Good luck!